# pandas read_excel() is reading thousands of empty lines and columns

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read an excel file with pandas read_excel() function. I have around 50 filled lines and 15 columns. Strangely the function adds thousands of empty columns and lines to the DataFrame. I tried skipping the empty cells, but it still does not work.

I assume that it has something to do with the formatting of the Excel file, but I can't find the exact reason.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I've had that happened.  My fix was to go into the excel file and highlight and delete (not clear) the empty rows

Comment: You could also try copying the data and pasting it into an entire new notebook.

Comment: If you know the number of columns you're looking for, you can use the `parse_cols` parameter in [pd.read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to have pandas read only those specified columns.

Comment: @3novak the parse_cols parameter did the job! Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas display extra unnamed columns for an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645135/pandas-display-extra-unnamed-columns-for-an-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be annoying, specially if a running R on a slow computer such as mine. I suggest one to erase all the useless cell formatting, such as borders and colors and delete every cell just after the last cell with data using CRTL + SHIFT + DOWN ARROW to select them.