# Pandas display extra unnamed columns for an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project using pandas library, in which I need to read an Excel file which has following columns:

```
'invoiceid', 'locationid', 'timestamp', 'customerid', 'discount', 'tax',
   'total', 'subtotal', 'productid', 'quantity', 'productprice',
   'productdiscount', 'invoice_products_id', 'producttax',
   'invoice_payments_id', 'paymentmethod', 'paymentdetails', 'amount'
```

But when I read this file by using the Python code below:

```
df_full = pd.read_excel('input/invoiced_products_noinvoiceids_inproduct_v2.0.xlsx', sheet_name=0,)
df_full.head()
```

it returns some rows along with 6 `unnamed` columns with values as `NAN`.I don't know why these columns are displaying here?

Below is the link to a sample file as requested:

https://mega.nz/#!0MlXCBYJ!Oim9RF56h6hUitTwqSG1354dIKLZEgIszzPrVpfHas8

Why are these extra columns appearing?

Comment: Is possible show file sample? Data shoudl be anonymized, header is important.

Comment: should I post a screenshot of file header along with 3-4 rows?

Comment: Better is upload file with anonymized data, dropbox, gdocs...

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I have uploaded a sample file and add a link in question.

Comment: seems to work fine [`with me`](https://imgur.com/a/l9DAc).. you are using any separators?

Comment: I'm only using above code.

Comment: can you try the same code on test.xlsx instead of the file you gave?

Comment: yup, it's also working fine for me, but when i load the actual file which is much bigger, then it displays 6 extra `unnamed` columns.

Comment: hmmm.. so i think there must be some extra data in columns that are not visible.. use filter property in excel after the last column and check whether a data is present or not after last column

Comment: how can I use that filter property? please!

Comment: check this [`file`](https://mega.nz/#!BTp1URaJ!8i3Px3hb42Grx-TEyjqAv83-c3aUJrnRhQn0jAgO5iw).. there is an extra data in 5th row I have added after last column.. you will get the same error.. hope you understand what I was trying to tell

Comment: @AbdulRehman - Already tested, working nice. Data are confidental?

Comment: i have tested your file, it's also displaying 1 extra `Unnamed: 18` column.

Comment: @AbdulRehman that's what I am telling  that might be present in your file

Comment: So, how can i clean that? please!

Comment: well you have to first check whether that is the only problem or its something else.. also if that's the problem whether you wanna ignore those fields..

Comment: Hi @rock321987, Of course, I don't need these extra columns, I just need columns till `amount` column.

Comment: use this `df_full = df_full[df_full.filter(regex='^(?!Unnamed)').columns]`

Comment: Hi @rock321987, it's working now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in comments the problem seems to be that, there is extra data after `last named` columns. That's why you are getting `Unnamed` columns.

If you wanna drop these columns this is how you can ignore these columns

```
df_full = df_full[df_full.filter(regex='^(?!Unnamed)').columns]
```